# Query dateadd compare with utc date

Tags: linq

How can I do this on linq?

```
  CONVERT(date,DATEADD(hour,9,TestDate)) = CONVERT(date, GETUTCDATE())
```

on UTC date.

I did this without success:

```
  a.Test.TestDate.AddHours(9) == DateTime.UtcNow
```

Comment: 1. Are you using Entity Framwork? 2. What does it mean "withot success"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EntityFramework you would need to use a combination of:

- [SqlFunctions.GetUtcDate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.getutcdate(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DbFunctions.AddHours()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.addhours(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [DbFunctions.TruncateTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx)

Example:

```
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DbFunctions.AddHours(a.Test.TestDate, 9)) ==
DbFunctions.TruncateTime(SqlFunctions.GetUtcDate())
```